# Proper patterns to react to redux store changes

Tags: javascript, redux

Usually in Redux we listen for actions in middleware/reducers to perform operations. However, at times we're not interested in actions, but in store changes themselves. This is especially relevant when multiple actions can lead to the same store changes. How can I do so in an idiomatic way?

Consider for example a section of the store in which we have the current path of a SPA:

```
const store = {
    url : '/'
};
```

Changing the url can happen in one of 3 ways: `popState`, `pushState` or `replaceState`. A logical implementation would be to have separate actions for the 3, such that we can handle them separately in middleware. E.g.:

```
//actions
function popState(url) {
  return { type : 'POP_STATE', url };
}
function pushState(url) { 
  return { type : 'PUSH_STATE', url };
}
function replaceState(url) {
  return { type : 'REPLACE_STATE', url };
}

// middleware
store => next => action => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'PUSH_STATE' : 
      history.pushState(null, null, action.url);
      break;
    case 'REPLACE_STATE' :
      history.replaceState(null, null, action.url);
      break;
  }
  return next(action);
}

// reducer
function (state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'PUSH_STATE':
    case 'REPLACE_STATE':
    case 'POP_STATE':
      state.url = action.url; // (ignoring immutability to keep the example simple)
      break;
  }
  return state;
}
```

Now I want to respond to url changes, but I don't care *how* the url changed. I see a few options, but I'm not sure if either of them follows the redux paradigms properly:

- Use `subscribe`

  This seems to be discouraged. From the docs:

  > It is a low-level API. Most likely, instead of using it directly, you'll use React (or other) bindings.
- Listen to all actions in middleware/reducer

  This only works properly in the simplest of cases. If the actions differ in structure, or if the full set of actions that change the state isn't known, then this won't work.
- Dispatch a new action (e.g. `STATE_CHANGED`) after reducing

  You can't directly dispatch an action in a reducer. This means you either need to use a timeout (subject to race conditions), or you need to spread out the logic over multiple `redux-thunk` style action creators.
- Use middleware to dispatch a new action

  This requires middleware to be aware of how all actions are reduced.

Do any of these solutions fall within the paradigms of redux? Did I miss any?

---

Meta note: I'm aware that this question could be interpreted as "primarily opinion based", but I disagree: I'm not looking for the best or most elegant solution, I'm trying to assert which solution(s) fit(s) the redux paradigm, and I believe there are definite, objective answers to that.

Comment: have you tried out any redux-binding? you can checkout [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org). it uses RxJS observable pattern to show new changes in the store. And as far dispatching goes, I guess you'll dispatch actions based on certain conditions independent of how the actions are being reduced,

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't find anything about listening to store changes in redux-observable. I only see a way of subscribing to actions, but that's not what I'm looking for. Am I missing something?

Comment: you can't subscribe to actions. you just dispatch them. you subscribe to the store and then you get new state in the subscribed listener by calling the getState method `store.getState()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `store.subscribe()` *is* a valid option if you need it.  There's [many existing libraries to help watch for changes in the store state](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#store-change-subscriptions) if you need to do so outside of connected React components.  Given that you're doing routing-related behavior, you may also be interested in [some of the existing Redux-based routing libraries](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/routing.md) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Good pattern  middleware :

```
const logMiddleware => ({ getState, dispatch }) => next => action => {
     console.log("Before reducers have run");
     console.log(getState());
     next(action);
     console.log("After the reducers have run");
     console.log(getState());
     };
```